# create a config file from args passed in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, config, argparse

I want to create a configuration variable section1.xml_file

config.py:

```
[section1]
xml_file = 'String1' + sys.argv[1] + 'String2'
```

Examples:

```
Input: config.py Test1

Output: xml_file = String1Test1String2

Input: config.py Test2

Output: xml_file = String1Test2String2
```

Comment: This is not a good question. What have you tried, what doesn't work etc? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for what constitutes a good question, how to ask it etc. It just looks like you have a homework assignment or work task you need to finish and are farming out the work to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to actually change the contents of a *config* file during runtime. A config is a static description of settings according to a certain environment, and it should not contain any magic that adapts the config settings itself to runtime parameters (such as `sys.argv`).

If you want to change the xml filename depending on the parameters passed to a python script, you can put the filename's format description into the config and then load that string during runtime and replace/insert individual parts. This has two major advantages:

1. the config's contents are consistent per environment
2. any other programmer can easily follow the settings

Your config file entry could look like this (I used an example that is less generic and closer to a real-world setup):

```
[assets]
xml_file_format = '/usr/share/basepath/{subpath:s}/assets/project.xml'
```

In your python code, you do:

```
import ConfigParser
cfg = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
xmlfile = cfg.get('assets', 'xml_file_format').format(subpath=sys.argv[1])
```

In case your *entire environment* is different depending on the passed `sys.argv[1]` and you want it to be fixed and consistent, you should create a config file for that certain environment and stick to it.

Comment: This gave me a solution.Thanks.